# OpenCl Segmentation Error at clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: opencl, convolution

I have been working on Convolution using OpenCL on Eclipse. It is giving a segmentation Fault after enqueueNDRangeKernel. 
Here is my host code: -

I have taken input image using OpenCV and then : -

```
const int width = image.size().width;
const int height = image.size().height;
std::cout<<"width: \t"<<width<<"\t height: "<<height<<std::endl;
std::size_t in_imagesize = (width*height)*sizeof(float);

std::vector<float> ptr(width*height,0);

const float filter[3] = {1,2,3};
float filter_size = 3*sizeof(float);
const int FilterRadius = 1;

cv::Mat result_image = cv::Mat(cvSize(width,height), CV_32FC1);
std::size_t out_imagesize = sizeof(float)*(width*height);
std::vector<float> read_buffer(width*height,0);
```

Then context, command queue, kernel program and after that: -

```
cl::Buffer input_dev, filter_kernel, output_dev;

input_dev = cl::Buffer(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PT R,in_imagesize,image.data,&err);
if(error!= CL_SUCCESS){
std::cout<<"Input Buffer Failed "<<std::endl;
}

output_dev =cl::Buffer(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,out_imagesize,NU LL,&err);
if(error!= CL_SUCCESS){
std::cout<<"Output Buffer Failed "<<std::endl;
}

filter_kernel = cl::Buffer(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,filter_size,NULL,& err);
if(error!= CL_SUCCESS){
std::cout<<"Output Buffer Failed "<<std::endl;


std::cout<<"filter_kernel write buffer "<<std::endl;
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(filter_kernel,CL_TRUE,0,3 *sizeof(float),filter,NULL,NULL);


// Create Kernel

std::cout<<"Now try create kernel objects .."<<std::endl;

cl::Kernel kernel(prg,"ConvH_naive",&err);
if(error!= CL_SUCCESS)
{
std::cout<<"create Kernel_naive failed \n"<<std::endl;
}
```

Then Kernel Arguments and after that: -

```
cl::NDRange globalsize(width,height);
cl::NDRange localsize(1,1);
cl::NDRange offset(0,0);


std::cout<<"Enqueuing the Kernel"<<std::endl;
if(queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,offset,global size,localsize,NULL,NULL)!=CL_SUCCESS)
{
std::cout<<"Failed enqueuing the Kernel"<<std::endl;
}
queue.finish();
```

After this Readbuffer and imshow. But the code stops after this statement giving a segmentation Fault.

Any one can help?? Is  it possible that there is problem is Kernel Code? Shall I add that too??

Comment: You can figure out yourself what is giving you a problem. First comment out the content of the kernel and check if it still seg faults after `enqueueNDRangeKernel`/`queue.finish()`. If not then the problem is in your kernel. Then step by step uncomment line by line (or some parts of the kernel if you want to do it faster) and retest.

Comment: Please add a minimum working example that someone can build and run. You've left out important parts like how you set the kernel arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. local size of (1,1) is typically a very bad choice
2. what platform are you running on? What device (e.g. CPU, GPU)?
3. It could be that you are segfaulting since you are not handling boundary conditions and accessing a buffer out of bounds.

Comment: Just to clarify, while a local size of (1,1) is suboptimal, it should not cause any errors (assuming the kernel itself is bug-free).